# XCeed WPF DataGrid: FilterCell for a specific property of converted value

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid, xceed-datagrid

I am using **XCeed DataGrid for WPF v4.0**. 
My data grid control has got one column with `FieldName=PropA`. Using `DisplayMemberBindingInfo` I convert its value to another class object with two properties in it ***1. Content 2. BackGroundColor***. Inside `CellContentTemplate` I use property **Content** as cell content and property **BackGroundColor** as background color of that cell. I am not able to understand how should I create FilterCell for this column so that I would be able to filter rows on cell **content**. Does `Converted Class` need to implement any interface for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is pretty simple:-

1) In such cases **never** apply converter on `DisplayMemberBindingInfo` of a column.***(If you do so then XCeed FilterCell applies filter on converted value.)***

2) Inside `CellContentTemplate` convert cellbinding to `Converted Class`. (Example:- place grid inside this template and assign converted value to its data context and then consume the data context to decorate your cell)